# ggplot remove the redundant x axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2)
a = sort(rep(c("A","B"),6))
b = c(rep(1:3,2),rep(4:6,2))
cc = rnorm(length(a))
d = rep(sort(rep(1:2,3)),2)
df = data.frame(a,b,cc,d)
print(df)
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(b), y = cc, fill = as.factor(d))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",   position = "dodge") + 
  facet_wrap(~a)
```

In the following plot:
How do I get rid of the redundant x-axis values for each of the factors of a i.e. "A" & "B".
I mean the 4:6 are not required for "A" and similarly 1:3 for "B".
What is the tweak I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`facet_wrap` and `facet_grid` both have a `scales` argument that let you define which of the `x` and/ or `y` scales should be free or fixed.

In your case, you want the `x` dimensions to be free to be different in both facets, therefore

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(b), y = cc, fill = as.factor(d))) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",   position = "dodge") + 
    facet_wrap(~ a, scales = 'free_x')
```

Comment: Wow it was that easy... Sorry for the bother should have read more. Stupid me.